# Storing, parsing and editing hundreds of XML files

Tags: xml, zend-framework, large-data

I have developed an interface where user will upload a zip file containing hundreds of XML files with XML files ranging from 200 to 8000 lines approximately.

Once the ZIP file is uploaded all the XML files has to be extracted and displayed to a user, since it is required for a user to manually edit the file and approve the content of XML file before it is moved and stored permanently in the server.

And from the permanent storage all the XML files are to be served back to requesting user through a private API call.

What is confusing me is the way the data should be stored in temporary or permanent storage, since it is required to edit, sort, paginate and search the content from the XML files.

I was exploring numerous options, some of them are.

1. Using MySql Database to store the data
2. Using Fulltext search engine like Apache Lucene to store (this may be bad idea, but not sure).
3. Storing it in permanent directory and reading/writing the files directly.

I was wondering if someone has come across similar problem, or what will be the feasible way to adopt to such situation ?

P.S : I am using Zend Framework with Doctrine for the application development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data is not used in any other way than as XML files (so no queries or searches through the data needed) than keeping the data in their files would be the best practice. Storing it in a database would add unneeded overhead especially because you keep converting the data back and forth between the db and XML.

If this is the case I would write a wrapper using for example SimpleXML (http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) that could perform basic tasks like looping through a XML file, saving rows etc. If you need to add some sort of search functionality you could possibly add something cool using DOMXPath (http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php).

If, on the other hand, the data will be needed in other ways (like an API, query searches etc) I would parse the incoming XML files and store them with in a database.

Ps. I would like add that if the client is not 100% clear about the long term intentions with the system and functionality (something only you can somehow determine) I would go for database storage despite the overhead if only XML format is used. Adding new functionality like calculations, searching, merging of data etc is not a problem if everything is stored neatly in a database. If you have a drive full of XML files you'll probably have to rewrite a lot of code.